# How to manage login window after session expire in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am testing Polarion application and after testing for couple of minutes session expires and login window pops up.

Session is expiring randomly hence I don't have any fixed point to stop and resume. My test case also starts failing as expected button is on the main window which become inactive after login window comes up.

My question is does Selenium provide any way to handle this scenario?

Using Selenium in Java/TestNg on Chrome.

Comment: does this happens when you are testing manually as well, if so, it's a product issue. and you should fix it product.

Comment: My guess is that the expiration is not random. It only seems random because you could be on any page when it expires, which also makes it difficult to predict and handle. My guess is that it's controlled by an cookie that is expiring after a fixed time. If you could identify that cookie and change it's expiration time/date, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `retryAnalyzer` of TestNG

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test001 {

@Test(retryAnalyzer = Tests.RetryAnalyzer.class)
public void Test1()
{
    Assert.assertEquals(false, true);
}

@Test
public void Test2()
{
    Assert.assertEquals(false, true);
}
```

}

The details you can find in below link :-

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/retry-failed-tests-testng/

Just write a function in retry which check if the pop-up appear then it call your login function.